# Read lines between two lines specified by their line number

Tags: bash, shell

How would I go about reading all lines between two specific lines?

Lets say line 23 is where I want to start, and line 56 is the last line to read, but it is not the end of the file.

How would I go about reading lines 23 thru 56? I will be outputting them to another file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By row number like that is quite easy with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR >= 23 && NR <= 56'
```

And either way, `sed` makes it fun.

```
sed '23,56!d'
```

Or for a pattern,

```
sed '/start/,/end/!d'
```

Comment: @Kevin `awk 'NR >= 23 && NR <= 56' file` doesn't do it, could you please provide the full command

Comment: @oleg It works on mine, perhaps your `awk` doesn't do default actions. Try `awk 'NR >= 23 && NR <= 56 { print $0 }' file`

Comment: `time awk 'NR >= 50000 && NR <= 60000' qwe > /dev/null` = 0m0.069s

Answer (score 6):

Sed can do that:

`$ sed -n 23,56p yourfile`

EDIT: as commenters pointed out making sed stop processing after the last line of the interval will make sed perform as fast as head-tail combination. So the most optimal way of getting the lines would be

`$ sed -n '23,56p;57q' yourfile`

But performance will greatly depend on the file you're processing, the interval and lots of other factors. So in case you're developing some script to be run frequently on known data testing all three methods mentioned in answers (sed, awk, head-tail) would be a good idea.

Comment: Well, sed has better performance than the `head`-`tail` combination (single process), especially if you are doing: `sed -n '23,56p;57q' FILE`.

Comment: 1+ for Zsoft: I like the 57q -- no more processing after that -- very cool.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for sed, but a head/tail combination is possible as well:

```
head -n 56 file | tail -n $((56-23))
```

Well - I'm pretty sure there is an off-by-one-error inside. I'm going to find it. :)

#### Update:

Haha - know your errors, I found it:

```
head -n 56 file | tail -n $((56-23+1))
```

Comment: !!! That's really interesting! With a file of 100,000 lines `time sed -n 50000,60000p qwe > /dev/null` = 0m0.015s and `time (head -n 60000 qwe | tail -n 10000 > /dev/null)` = 0m0.003s -- KEP THINGS SIMPLE

Comment: In most cases you loose more time by typing the head/tail combination (and finding the off-by-one error) than you'll save, compared to sed.

Comment: it all depends on what's the purpose of the command - if it's a part of some frequently executed job then it would be worth it

Comment: Yes. Looked more like a one-time-job to me. Testing with some own files, dictionaries are of sufficient length (ogerman, utf-german, pgdict) I get smaller differences (1:2 to 1:4).

Comment: @Oleg With 60000q on the sed, I get sed running twice as fast as head|tail.  Without it, they run about the same speed.  Are you sure of your timings?

Comment: @WilliamPursell adding `;60000q` lowers sed execution time from 15ms to 10ms for me. My benchmarks don't have much sense anyway - just making OP aware that in case he's programming scripts that are going to get executed thousands of times at some huge datawarehouse performance numbers start to matter.

Comment: this is some good pieces of info. I wish I programmed for a huge datawarehouse =D.

Answer (score 3):

use sed. This should do it.

```
   sed -n '23,56p' > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1,22d;56q' file
```

or this:

```
sed '23,56!d;56q' file
```

or this:

```
awk 'NR>56{exit};NR==23,NR==56' file
```